# Allow slow connections to upload images with NGINX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, nginx

So I just set up my latest rails-application running ruby 2.1.2 and rails 4.1 together with Nginx and Passenger under Ubuntu.

Now I need the administrator of this website to upload images for his projects. The problem is that while I successfully allowed a basically unlimited filesize to be uploaded nginx still throws out an error if the connection is too slow.

The admin uploads X images at a time but his upload speed is drastically slow so it kind of takes him 1 hour to upload a few images.
This isn't a problem about it taking so long, but nginx throwing out errors right after the upload was done because the connection seems to be lost somewhere in the middle of the uploading process.

So my question: How can I allow slow connections to upload all their files at once without having to worry about nginx anymore?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Is it really needed to let users to upload files of unlimited size?

Comment: Not necessarily, no. It's just that some files are ~200MB of size (videos) while others are sized within 150KB - 5MB.

The actual problem is that slow connections take too long for the whole upload so nginx 'forgets' about the connection (which is good, for the most parts).

Comment: I think you should check your server configuration for that timeout exception.

Comment: It is set to 10 minutes already, however, I do not really want to keep all connections alive for THAT long. There's a reason its default length is set to 1 minute. Other than that, I can never tell for sure how long the uploading process is gonna take. It could be a few minutes but 2 hours wouldn't be anything too special either.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [nginx upload module](http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html)?

It have an interesting `upload_resumable` option.

Comment: Not yet, as I think using javascript/ajax requests is more of a nice addon, however, does not solve my problem.